# Properly format postgres interval to HH:MM

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to calculate time interval in postgre,

```
SELECT 
    employee_id,
    clock_in,
    clock_out,
    (SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM (clock_out-clock_in))/3600) AS time_worked
FROM
    payroll_timelog
WHERE
    employee_id=31;
```

I am trying to format this to `HH:MM` format but I get base 10 floating points `7.975380470833334`.

[image]

This should be 7.58 (7 hours 58 mins). This precision is important.

I tried casting to int:

```
(SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM (clock_out-clock_in))::int/3600) AS time_worked
```

but that rounds down to `7`.

How can I make sure to get the desired result of 7.58?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use [`TO_CHAR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) with `HH24:MI` format after subtracting from two datetime.

```
SELECT 
    employee_id,
    clock_in,
    clock_out,
    TO_CHAR(clock_out - clock_in,'HH24:MI')
FROM
    payroll_timelog
WHERE
    employee_id=31;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d89646d0323d4368436c22ba3c01c58c)